Question that seems opinion-based when someone does not know the objective answer
A question in the form of: "Can X be done in game Y?" can be seem opinion based, however If in fact you know that there is a variant of game Y where X has been implemented then the question is no longer opinion based, because the answer is objective: Yes, see X in Y at Z.
I am talking about two questions that were asked today:

Redesign Checkers board to an odd size
Redesign Ludo with more than 4 players

both questions have an objective answer: "Yes, here and there it is implemented."

Just because something "can" be done doesn't mean you won't get multiple different opinions oh how it should be done or if it should be done. In all honesty those do not seem like good questions and at best should be closed as game recommendations which are off topic,

The questions are "Is it possible..." / "Can X in Y...?"  Not if it should.  Therefore there is an objective easy answer: yes, it has been done.

And the answer is obviously yes that it can be done but that doesn't mean that it will make for a good version of the game. There is nothing stopping someone from making a checkers board with a different number of rows/columns and it doesn't even need to end up as a square. Also there is nothing stopping someone from making a ludo board that supports a larger or smaller number of players.

The body text of each of those questions asks whether it is possible to have the game with a particular variation, and as you say, the answer is objectively "yes" (trivially so for checkers, I think). But the title of each question asks for a "redesign", which indicates that they are looking for something more than "yes, you can". Design is inherently an open-ended and opinionated process, so it makes sense that people would interpret the questions as opinion based.

Taken literally, at face value, and out of context, you're right, those aren't necessarily opinion-based. But in context, past face value, they're opinion-based. And either way they're not good questions and closing them is appropriate.
So, yes, both questions are ostensibly answerable as-is. We don't even need to cite an example. Obviously yes you can play checkers with an odd-sized grid: just remove or add a column. It'll play different, but it'll still look like checkers. Obviously you can play Ludo with more than four players: just add more home spaces, the same way the game already does when you're moving from 2 players up to 3 or 4. But it's so trivially answerable it's still a bad question. The answer is plain and obvious and there's not even trivial research effort shown in asking it.
That's all taking it solely at face value which we don't have to do.
Stack Exchange isn't just about writing answers to questions. We are about solving peoples' problems, which means looking deeper at the actual problem someone is experiencing and trying to figure that out. There's only a certain range of questions we accept, and that range represents this mission. If we look past the surface-level question (which, as mentioned, is a bad question) we find the actual problem here is someone's curious about alternative design lenses, but rather than do their own exploration they're asking us a bad subjective question:

To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …

there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”


The author has no actual apparent problem here, they're just shooting off hypotheticals and asking us about them (“what if checkers had an odd sized grid?”). That's both of these bullet points. The main function of the full list of bullet points is to direct us away from discussion-y conversation starters that's suitable for a forum but doesn't work here, and toward the kind of Q&A that thrives in our system.
We also have to observe the querent was showing they were going to perform a pattern of these questions, a pattern that likely stopped at two because our downvotes and close votes enforced an automatic slowdown or question ban.
So taking in the full context:

The questions showed no actual research effort, and so were not up to our quality bar and were downvoted.
Whether at face value or past face value, the questions were bad subjective and presented no actual problem and were too open-ended for our format, which would require them to be closed as either primarily opinion-based or for more information required because we need them to better define what problem they're actually running into.
This was going to be a series of questions, which we needed to hit the brakes on. Downvoting and especially closing is our brakes.

Downvoting these questions and closing them as primarily opinion-based was appropriate. If it wasn't for POB, they'd be closed as unclear & more information needed to understand their problem. The important thing is they're closed, so opening them to re-close them for a different reason isn't wortwhile.
